# AngularJs:-Angular based CMS panel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress, content-management-system

I'm thinking about making a sort of admin panel in angularjs. I need a way to edit the content of the site, like e.g. Wordpress offers (basically a CMS).

The confusing bit is how the CMS and Angular would integrate together

In other CMSs, the creation of the views happens on the server side. In Angular we creare a HTML template, which you can populate with data in an angular controller.

I am a bit stuck as to how to define templates and then on click position the templates accordingly..
Please suggest a way to help achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Althought you seem to have an understanding how Angular works, some fundamental information is missing in your question. I guess you want to persist the content of the CMS, so you have to provide some details about the server part (I don't think you are going to use clientside storage solutions).

Additionally your question how to position templates is a bit confusing. Typically you are not dynamically positioning templates. Rather you have a template and position some elements inside of the templates. You should concretise your problem here.

Maybe you want to use some existing CMS solutions based on Angular like:

- http://respondcms.com/
- https://github.com/jonniespratley/angular-cms